# Volume icon in menu bar disappear randomly in Big Sur

Tags: macos, terminal, menu-bar, sound-volume, big-sur

Since I updated to Big Sur, my volume icon disappear and I always have to go on Preferences to display it again. I don't know what's the reason.

Is there a solution to that ? Is there a terminal command to make it appear again next time ?

Comment: It’s possible you’ve set it to only show when active. Go to `System Preferences`> `Dock & Menu Bar` > `Sound` and underneath the box `Show in menu bar`, make sure you’ve enabled it to show always. Otherwise the volume menu bar item will only show if you are actively turning it up/down and disappear from the menu bar other times

Comment: I have the same problem. It disappears every time I restart the Mac. The solution above doesn't work because it is already set to `always`

Comment: I have the same problem. Running on macOS 11.0.1.

Comment: Yep same problem. Utterly frustrating bug.

Comment: do you have a lot of 3rd party menu items?

Comment: I have this same issue. I think it's happening when I disconnect my eGPU since several apps crash when I do that, even though I use the "disconnect eGPU" menu bar icon. That's my best guess atm.

I experience the same symptoms, the checkbox to show volume control on the menu bar gets unchecked, and I re-check it. That works until the next "crash" unchecks it.

Big Sur 11.2.3 on Macbook Pro 2019.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

I know why this happens.  Upon clicking the volume icon in the menu bar, if you misclick/misdrag anywhere but the allowable volume change slider it will interpret this as trying to rearrange the menu bar icon to another menu bar location.

My current "fix" is to use the open the control center menu and drag the volume back into the menu bar every time this happens.

EDIT: Seems to be fixed in MacOS 11.3

Comment: omg ‍♂️ how did u notice that lol

Comment: Terrible software issue. Agree

Answer (score 6):

I also have the same problem; I need to go to `System Preferences` -> `Sound` -> `Show volume in menu bar` every the other day!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this only happened to me whenever I set Mac to reopen my windows after a restart.

This is weird, but if you really don't need to reopen your windows, then you can just uncheck that box when restarting or shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem until I made the change that Aveij described and the icon has not had this problem since.

No idea why they made a change that makes a control that I use many times a day disappear.